# Showing that $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}\right)$ is in $\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to check the infinite derivatives part in this exercise.

[Wong, An introduction to pseudo differential operators]
Exercise 3.1.

Let $\varphi$ be the function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\varphi(x)=\begin{cases} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}\right),\quad |x|<1\\
0,\quad |x|\geq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

My attempt:  Induction on the large of $\alpha$ multi index.

Case $|x|<1$

Affirmation. $\forall \alpha$ multi index, $\partial_{x_j}^{\alpha}\psi(|x|^2)=\frac{p_{\alpha}(|x|)}{q_{\alpha}(|x|)}\psi(|x|^2)$ (where $\psi(t)=\exp(-\frac{1}{1-t})$) for some $p_{\alpha}$, $q_{\alpha}$ polynomials.

Proof: If $|\alpha|=1$, $\partial_{x_j}\psi(|x|^2)=-\frac{2x_j}{(1-|x|^2)}\psi(|x|^2)$.

Assuming that the statement is valid for multi index of length $l$, let's prove for a multi index of length $l + 1$.

\begin{eqnarray}\partial_{x_j}\partial^{\alpha}(\psi(|x|^2))&=&\partial_{x_j}\frac{p_{\alpha}(|x|)}{q_{\alpha}(|x|)}\psi(|x|^2)\\
&=&(\partial_{x_j} \psi(|x|^2)+\psi(|x|^2)\partial_{x_j}\left(\frac{p_{\alpha}(|x|)}{q_{\alpha}(|x|)}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

To conclude that the function is in $\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}$   I need to see the differentiability (by definition) when $|x| = 1$? right?

Comment: Your function is the composition of the squared norm and $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $t\mapsto\exp(-1/t)$ for $t>0$ and $0$ for $t\le 0$.So, no need to calculate *partial* derivatives.